# Get Rid of 'Compass Interference' Message while using compass through NSLocationManager

Tags: gps, augmented-reality, compass-geolocation

I am working on augmented reality with GPS & Camera interface but more often I am having this calibration message as 'Compass Interference' see image.

[a busy cat http://static.iphonelife.com/sites/iphonelife.com/files/imagecache/teaser_thumb/u2440/compass8.jpg](http://static.iphonelife.com/sites/iphonelife.com/files/imagecache/teaser_thumb/u2440/compass8.jpg)

this is appearing very often, while in other apps it working fine with very less such messages.
Is there any thing needs to be changed or is it normal.

Comment: Facing the same issue..Did u got any solution for that..Please help me out...